# Regex in SQL Server, match anything except a letter

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, string

I'm trying to write some regex in SQL Server to match anything before or after a string except a letter.

`'%ABC%'` doesn't work as it includes letters.

`'%[^a-z]ABC[^a-z]%'` doesn't work because it wont match with any query where the result starts or ends with `ABC`. Because `[^a-z]` means any character that is not a letter character, but a character nonetheless.

The regex to solve this would be:

```
[^a-z]ABC[^a-z]|ABC[^a-z]|[^a-z]ABC
```

but you cant write this in SQL as:

```
'%[^a-z]ABC[^a-z]|ABC[^a-z]|[^a-z]ABC%'
```

or

```
'%[^a-z]ABC[^a-z]%|%ABC[^a-z]%|%[^a-z]ABC%'
```

I don't want to use `OR` in my SQL, as I have a stored procedure that includes:

```
WHERE var like @var
```

and I'd be executing it with something like

```
@var = '%[^a-z]APU[^a-z]%'
```

and I'd rather not have multiple parameters or try and pass multiple values to a single parameter.

Is there a way to tweak the regex of `'%[^a-z]ABC[^a-z]%'` Such that `ABC` can start or end the string?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  And this is perfectly valid in SQL Server:  '%[^a-z]APU[^a-z]%'.  Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: `'%[^a-z]ABC[^a-z]%'` is not a *regex*, it is a wildcard pattern.

Comment: @Olivia check here i think you will the solution [here](http://www.guru99.com/regular-expressions.html)

Comment: Please check my answer if its works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as:

```
where ' ' + var + ' ' like '%[^a-z]ABC[^a-z]%'
```

That will match patterns at the beginning and end of the string as well.

I'm not sure if this really meets your requirement, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this CLR code to use real regexes in SQL Server
See after code, the SQL sentence to add into the functions in your SQL Server instance

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

namespace XXX.DotNet.XXX
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Cette classe est utilisée pour mettre à disposition une librairie de fonctions d'Expressions Régulières destinées pour SQL Server 2005 (et plus) en CLR
    /// </summary>
    public class RegularExpressionFunctions
    {
        /**
        <summary>
        Cette méthode permet de récupérer toutes les sous-chaines d'une chaine correspondant à une expression régulière (sous forme de chaine concaténée)
        </summary>
        <param name="pattern">
        Cette chaîne de caractères représente l'expression régulière à comparer
        </param>
        <param name="sentence">
        Cette chaîne de caractères représente l'expression à évaluer
        </param>
        <param name="separator">
        Cette chaîne de caractères sera insérée entre chaque sous-chaîne
        </param>
        <returns>
        Soit null si aucune sous-chaine ne correspond, soit une chaine correspondant à la concaténation des différentes sous-chaînes séparées par une chaîne de séparation
        </returns>
        */
        [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true, Name = "RegExMatches")]
        public static String RegExMatches(String pattern, String sentence, String separator)
        {
            Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
            MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(sentence);
            int nbFound = matches.Count;
            if(nbFound == 0){return null;}// Retourne null si aucune sous-chaîne ne correspond à l'expression régulière
            String toReturn = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < nbFound; i++)
            {
                Match match = matches[i];
                if(i != 0)
                {
                    toReturn += separator;
                }
                toReturn += match.Value;
            }
            return toReturn;// Retourne les sous-chaînes séparées par la chaîne de séparation
        }

        /**
        <summary>
        Cette méthode permet de récupérer toutes les sous-chaines d'une chaine correspondant à une expression régulière (sous forme de tableau)
        </summary>
        <param name="pattern">
        Cette chaîne de caractères représente l'expression régulière à comparer
        </param>
        <param name="sentence">
        Cette chaîne de caractères représente l'expression à évaluer
        </param>
        <returns>
        Un tableau de taille égale au nombre de sous-chaîne trouvées, contenant dans chaque case une sous-chaîne correspondant à l'expression régulière
        </returns>
        */
        [SqlFunction(Name = "RegExMatchesSplit", FillRowMethodName = "NextSplitRow", DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
        public static IEnumerable RegExMatchesSplit(String pattern, String sentence)
        {
            Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
            MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(sentence);
            int nbFound = matches.Count;
            //String[][] toReturn = new String[nbFound][];
            String[] toReturn = new String[nbFound];
            for(int i = 0; i < nbFound; i++)
            {
                /*toReturn[i] = new String[2];
                toReturn[i][0] = sentence;
                toReturn[i][1] = matches[i].Value;*/
                toReturn[i] = matches[i].Value;
            }
            return toReturn;// Retourne les sous-chaînes dans un tableau
        }
        public static void NextSplitRow(Object obj, /*out SqlString sentence, */out SqlString match)
        {
            /*String[] row = (String[])obj;
            sentence = new SqlString(row[0]);
            match = new SqlString(row[1]);*/
            match = new SqlString(obj.ToString());
        }

        /**
        <summary>
        Cette méthode permet de récupérer le nombre de sous-chaînes d'une chaîne correspondant à une expression régulière
        </summary>
        <param name="pattern">
        Cette chaîne de caractères représente l'expression régulière à comparer
        </param>
        <param name="sentence">
        Cette chaîne de caractères représente l'expression à évaluer
        </param>
        <returns>
        Le nombre d'occurences des sous-chaînes trouvée par l'expression régulière dans la chaîne d'entrée
        </returns>
        */
        [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true, Name = "RegExNbMatches")]
        public static int RegExNbMatches(String pattern, String sentence)
        {
            return new Regex(pattern).Matches(sentence).Count;// Retourne le nombre de sous-chaînes trouvées
        }

        /**
        <summary>
        Cette méthode permet de savoir si une chaîne de caractère correspond à un pattern d'expression régulière
        </summary>
        <param name="pattern">
        Cette chaîne de caractères représente l'expression régulière à comparer
        </param>
        <param name="sentence">
        Cette chaîne de caractères représente l'expression à évaluer
        </param>
        <returns>
        True si l'expression correspond bien au pattern, false dans le cas contraire
        </returns>
        */
        [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true, Name = "RegExIsMatch")]
        public static bool RegExIsMatch(String pattern, String sentence)
        {
            return new Regex(pattern).IsMatch(sentence);
        }

        /**
        TODO - Documentation
        */
        [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true, Name = "RegExMatch")]
        public static String RegExMatch(String pattern, String sentence)
        {
            Match match = new Regex(pattern).Match(sentence);
            if(!match.Success){return null;}
            return match.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Compile with Framework 3.5 the following command can help

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe" /t:library RegularExpressionFunctions.cs
```

Once compiled, put the DLL into `C:\CLR\Regex\`
(or elsewhere and change the following SQL Query according)

Then add the functions with the following code and test with the Query that comes next

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
-- Drop des fonctions pré-existantes
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.RegExMatches')) DROP FUNCTION dbo.RegExMatches
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.RegExNbMatches')) DROP FUNCTION dbo.RegExNbMatches
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.RegExMatchesSplit')) DROP FUNCTION dbo.RegExMatchesSplit
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.RegExIsMatch')) DROP FUNCTION dbo.RegExIsMatch
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.RegExMatch')) DROP FUNCTION dbo.RegExMatch
GO
-- Drop de l'assembly pré-existante puis recréation de celle-ci
IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM sys.assemblies asms WHERE asms.name = N'RegExFunction' ) DROP ASSEMBLY [RegExFunction]
CREATE ASSEMBLY RegExFunction FROM 'C:\CLR\Regex\RegularExpressionFunctions.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
GO
-- Création des fonctions
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RegExMatches(@pattern NVARCHAR(MAX), @sentence NVARCHAR(MAX), @separator NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS EXTERNAL NAME RegExFunction.[XXX.DotNet.XXX.RegularExpressionFunctions].RegExMatches
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RegExNbMatches(@pattern NVARCHAR(MAX), @sentence NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS INT
AS EXTERNAL NAME RegExFunction.[XXX.DotNet.XXX.RegularExpressionFunctions].RegExNbMatches
GO
--CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RegExMatchesSplit(@pattern NVARCHAR(MAX), @sentence NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS TABLE (Sujet NVARCHAR(MAX), Match NVARCHAR(MAX))
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RegExMatchesSplit(@pattern NVARCHAR(MAX), @sentence NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS TABLE (Match NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS EXTERNAL NAME RegExFunction.[XXX.DotNet.XXX.RegularExpressionFunctions].RegExMatchesSplit
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RegExIsMatch(@pattern NVARCHAR(MAX), @sentence NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS BIT
AS EXTERNAL NAME RegExFunction.[XXX.DotNet.XXX.RegularExpressionFunctions].RegExIsMatch
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RegExMatch(@pattern NVARCHAR(MAX), @sentence NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS EXTERNAL NAME RegExFunction.[XXX.DotNet.XXX.RegularExpressionFunctions].RegExMatch
GO
```

Use the following Query to test your functions

```
DECLARE @sentence NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @regex NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @regex2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @separator NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sentence = 'ABABCCADSQDJIOAZF JAIPZDJKL MNJKCXNjnaze iodjazpdjadpazdoa zdjio'
SET @regex = '[A-z]{6}\ '
SET @regex2 = '^[^a-z]*ABC[^a-z]*$'
SET @separator = ';'
SELECT @regex as 'Regex', @sentence as 'Sentence', dbo.RegExMatch(@regex2, match) FROM dbo.RegExMatchesSplit(@regex, @sentence);
SELECT @regex as 'Regex', @sentence as 'Sentence', dbo.RegExMatches(@regex2, dbo.RegExMatches(@regex, @sentence, @separator), @separator)
SELECT @regex as 'Regex', @sentence as 'Sentence', dbo.RegExNbMatches(@regex,@sentence)
SELECT @regex as 'Regex', @sentence as 'Sentence', dbo.RegExIsMatch(@regex,@sentence)
SELECT @regex as 'Regex', @sentence as 'Sentence', dbo.RegExMatch(@regex2, dbo.RegExMatch(@regex,@sentence))
GO
```